# Uploading a single file returns 403 forbidden error

Tags: flutter, dart, file-upload, multipart

Whenever I try to upload a single file to the server through multipart request, it returns 403 forbidden error

The code I tried

```
 request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
                                'attachment_files[]',
                                File(uploadList[i]['file']).path));
```

[The error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA7J3.png)

If I upload multiple files at once then it works fine!

Comment: Error is not directly flutter dependant. It is a server error.
403 is a Forbidden error code. It mean that server understand you request, but can't execute your request. This is true if the server is well devellopped and respond with the right code accordingly to what happen.

Comment: So what to do if situation like that occurs?

Comment: You need to investigate why server is responding with a 403 HTTP code.

Comment: Btw, while hitting the server from postman it's working but when tried to upload a file from application it gives 403 and server is not a localhost

Comment: Check the log and source code of server to find what is the problem.

Comment: I have checked the logs and there isn't any error related to 403. I don't understand

Comment: Did you write yourself the background? or have access to the sourcecode? If yes, check the source code to see where backend return a 403 error.

Comment: I haven't coded the back-end so I do not know. I just have access to the API

Comment: Ok, if backend have a good documentation, check it to find what are the conditions that conduct backend to send back a 403 error code. If not only you can do is trying to reproduce the error with Postman to understand what's happen.

Comment: Is there any other solution for it? The back-end team is clueless and thinks it's the problem on my end.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens when you had not define `MIME` type OR `content` type following is the right way to do it.

```
 @override
 Future<http.StreamedResponse?> multipartPostHttp({
   required String endPoint,
   Map<String, String>? headers,
   Map<String, dynamic>? requestBody,
   required String fileFieldName,
   required String filePath,
 }) async {
  try {
    http.MultipartFile file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
     fileFieldName,
     filePath,
     contentType: MediaType("image", getFileType(filePath)),
    );

    // call http request
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("Post", Uri.parse(endPoint))
      ..headers.addAll(headers!)
      ..fields.addAll(requestBody! as Map<String, String>)
      ..files.add(file);

    return request.send();
   } on Exception catch (_) {
       return null;
   }
}
```